# How to execute API call on flutter and send response to native side Android / IOS using method channel onBackground?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, onesignal

I want to show OnesSignal background notification based on condition which requires to call API and based on API response will decide to show/hide the notification from native Android / IOS side using method channel onBackground ?

Note : the background handler method are only available at native side Android / IOS.

Comment: Instead of using method channels you can use flutter packages to show notifications.
flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0  or           awesome_notifications: ^0.7.4+1

Comment: @Aks i've updated the question it's oneSignal notification i want to show/ hide
on background. as oneSignal does not provide any background handler method for flutter side.

Comment: - In one of my app I used method channel to call dart code from native side (in background) it was working in debug mode only but It was not working in release mode.

SOLUTION:- work on native side (ios/android) background handler method and handle notification from both side.